# Django: Add a placeholder text to default comment textarea field

Tags: python, django

I want to simply add a placeholder text for the textarea input in the default Django comments module. How can I go on to achieve this? Would I need to create an new CommentForm class and reference that instead or is it possible to just add this attribute?

My current code in the init file for comments,

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.comments.forms import CommentDetailsForm

class CommentForm(CommentDetailsForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail address"), required=False)

def get_form():
    return CommentForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `__init__` method of form (and not only there) you can modify any attributes of fields, even swap fields with other types. All fields are stored in dictionary `self.fields`. So all you need to do is:

```
class CommentForm(CommentDetailsForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail address"), required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field_to_add_placeholder_to'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = "your placeholder"
```

Comment: I see, thanks. I tried adding a placeholder to the textarea (I assume I just set "textarea" as reference?) but it had no effect. Is it possible that I need to restart the env?